# Scene editor does not display grid

Tags: xcode, editor, scenekit

Somehow my scene editor fails to display helper tools (cameras, grid etc) in the design area. As the images shows I've enabled all tools but none of them are visible. I have tried to reset to default and also did a reinstall of Xcode, without success. Any suggestions?

[image: Scene editor]

Answer (score 4):

In recent Xcode versions you can right-click in the scene and get the menu you need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While in the SceneKit editor, in the menu bar click on Editor > Display > Show Grid

edit: In Xcode 10 the display menu is no longer available in the editor. You have to right click in the SceneKit Editor to access it.